# Does mysql revoke user privilege automatically?

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a beginner learning to use apache, phpmyadmin, and mysql on Ubuntu. In the Ubuntu console, I'm logged in as root and created a new user 'new_user'. Then I run:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 'new_user'@'localhost'
```

Then, I logged into phpmyadmin with *new_user* and under the User tab, I tried to give myself GRANT privileges (This was the only privilege that was unchecked for this user, so I checked it to see what would happen). When I tried to do this, phpmyadmin displayed an access denied error (which is understandable as I think only root can do this).

However, when I refreshed phpmyadmin and tried to log in again with *new_user*, I noticed that all privileges are revoked. I had to log in with root via the console and grant *new_user* all privileges again.

Is this normal behaviour? Did MySQL automatically revoke all privileges for *new_user* because *new_user* did something it wasn't supposed to?

Comment: did you do `flush privileges`? otherwise those alterations do not activate

Comment: I used flush privileges after granting all privileges to 'new_user', but I did not use flush privileges after privileges were revoked for  'new_user'